# Flask-Admin Batch Actions with Ajax

Tags: python, flask-admin

I'm using a batch action that does some 'heavy lifting' with the selected rows. Therefore, after choosing the action, the page freezes for some time until it returns with Flash message.

Is there a way to customize the behavior (or an elegant workaround) to give feedback to the users on the progress of the action, while it's happening?

I could not find an answer to this on the [documentation](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/#customizing-batch-actions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. You don't have a `Flask-Admin` way to do it.

If it is a long running task, you can handle it in background, using `celery`, `rq` or any other queue technology. This way, you return faster, but your task is still running. Just you can evaluate if it works for you.

If this solution does not fit your problem, you always can extend `Flask-Admin` to do anything the way you want.

I have some "actions" where I start the task in background and another page do polling to check if it is finished, but you use `Flask-Admin` just as a framework, it's not built-in.

Comment: After this answer, I'm sure it is possible to create a `LongRunningAction` class in `Flask-Admin` to make it work.